# Cannot read image files, css and script libraries using absolute and relative url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

From public_html folder I am redirecting a domain to a specific folder to load and view a website. code was written in `PHP`. The root folder of the website is home/new/www.mysite.com where www.mysite.com is the folder of the website that contain index.php and assets.

I define my root folder as `MYROOT`.

In my index.php I have this line of code.

```
$mypaths = explode('/', ltrim($parse_url['path'], '/'));        
if($mypaths ['0']){
    $mypaths ['0'] = "page";
    if(file_exists($mypaths ['1'].'.php')){
        $mybody = $mypaths ['1'].'.php';
    }
        else $mybody = MYROOT.'/home.php';

}else{
    $mybody = MYROOT.'/home.php';
}
include(MYROOT.'/header.php');
include($mybody );
include(MYROOT.'/footer.php');
```

`header.php` includes navigation of the website and all stylesheet linked.
`$mybody` is where the body of the website will show.
`footer.php` the footer of the website.

From there, it only shows html code of the site (no css style, no images!)
Tried to change all my href link from `href="../assets/style.css"` to `href="<?=MYROOT?>/assets/style.css"` as well as my images. But it does not get the image file and styles.

Turning on my `display_errors` but not getting any error, but browser's debug tool have errors, including:

1.`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

2.`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Why absolute and relative url's are not working here?

Additional info: I have my .htaccess which contains

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

I am also running the website on my server. Pointing the domain to my server's ip address using hosts file.

Comment: I don't know php, but php code not need to be wrapped in some tags like <?php ..... <php>?

Comment: @pookie what did you mean? PHP code should be within `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: @Redo not entirely sure ;) just seem to remember having to wrap php code in some tags the one time I encountered it.

Comment: It should have `<? ?>` or `<?php ?>` especially when including some html code.

Comment: your path must be wrong. And only absolute path can work. Check your php and html code again also, it might have errors, rearranage and rewrite you might be able to rectify the error.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ [L]

Comment: Yup absolutely your right. But both absolute and relative paths didn't work for me.

Comment: @ashup. Do I need to add this on my .htaccess?

Comment: Try please and do you have <base href="/"> added in html?
and check weather you have no error in css or js

href="<?php echo MYROOT; ?>/assets/style.css"

Comment: nope, I don't have <base> in my html.. Tried the rewriterule doesn't change anything..